# How to convert python HEX ouput to ASCII?

Tags: python, sockets, hex, ascii, pyshark

I'd like to convert HEX output in python to ASCII when i'm using LiveCapture from pyshark.

My code:

```
capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='en1',
                              bpf_filter='tcp port 5555 and len > 66',)

colored.OK("Interface bindée sur %s" % socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))

for packet in capture.sniff_continuously():
   if packet.ip.src == socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()):
            colored.OK("Send packets")
   else:
            colored.OK("Receive packets")
            print(''.join(packet.data.data.split(":")))
            print("")
```

Output for receive packets:

```
66787874798582124495051
```

I'd like to convert this output to ASCII char directly in the python output
Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can convert it directly.

```
def convert_HEX_to_ASCII(h):
chars_in_reverse = []
while h != 0x0:
    chars_in_reverse.append(chr(h & 0xFF))
    h = h >> 8

chars_in_reverse.reverse()
return ''.join(chars_in_reverse)

print (convert_HEX_to_ASCII(0x6176656e67657273))
print (convert_HEX_to_ASCII(0x636f6e766572745f4845585f746f5f4153434949))
```

Refer link, which convert HEX to ASCII online. https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-hex.html
You can verify the output manually and confirm the result.

Similar code is available on :
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-hexadecimal-value-string-ascii-value-string/